# Fabric-CA-Server, validate user with password

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I've enrolled admin and user using fabric-sdk by giving my own secret(password). I've seen that when I use getUserContext('user1',true) function it is returning me user with out asking secret that I set, during enrollment. Can someone please let me know, how do I set the password check for this.

Answer (score 0):

Enrollment secret is given after registration and NOT enrollment. This secret is used to carry out the enrollment process. What I assume you want is an authentication system/login?

Comment: That's correct, I'm looking to have authentication.

Comment: You will need to implement it on your own. I have tried searching for documentation/tutorials but haven't found any. Others have suggested mapping the username to a password and his keys on another db ( on chat.hyperledger.org  and other similar questions like these)